# Why are the result files not being generated for each counter in the new directory?

Tags: bash, perf

I am attempting to use the Linux perf tool to monitor counters. I am measuring counters in intervals of 500 milliseconds over a span of 10 minutes. I am trying to output the results of each counter into their own respective output files in a new directory. The new directory is created but I am only getting a hidden .txt file within it. I would like for files to be generated for each counter and their respective results to populate those files.

Here is the script:

```
     #!/bin/bash

     # Set the duration (in seconds) for monitoring
     duration=$((10 * 60))

     # Create an array of counters to monitor
     counters=(
               "cpu/event=0x00,umask=0x01,name=branch-instructions/"
               "cpu/event=0x00,umask=0x02,name=branch-misses/"
               "cpu/event=0x00,umask=0x0e,name=bus-cycles/"
               "cpu/event=0x00,umask=0x08,name=cache-misses/"
               "cpu/event=0x00,umask=0x00,name=instructions/"
               "msr/aperf/"
               "msr/mperf/"
               "msr/pperf/"
               "msr/smi/"
               "msr/tsc/"
               "power/energy-cores/"
               "power/energy-pkg/"
               "power/energy-ram/"
    )

    # Get the start time
    start_time=$(date +%s)

    # Create a directory to store the output files
    output_dir="perf_results"
    mkdir -p "$output_dir"

    # Iterate through each counter and monitor them
    for counter in "${counters[@]}"; do
    # Extract the counter name for file storage
         counter_name=$(echo "$counter" | awk -F"/" '{print $NF}')

         # Create an output file for the counter
         output_file="${output_dir}/${counter_name}.txt"

         # Run perf command to monitor the counter at each interval and append to the file
         run=1
         while true; do
              measurement=$(perf stat -a -e "$counter" -I 500 sleep 0.5 2>&1)
              {
                   echo "Run: $run"
                   echo "Time: $(date)"
                   echo "Counter: $counter_name"
                   echo "Measurement: $measurement"
                   echo
              } >> "$output_file"

              # Check if the duration has elapsed
              current_time=$(date +%s)
              elapsed_time=$((current_time - start_time))
              if [ "$elapsed_time" -ge "$duration" ]; then
                  break
              fi

              ((run++))
         done &
     done

    # Wait for the monitoring to complete
    wait

    # Display a message indicating the monitoring is finished
    echo "Monitoring completed."
```

The output directory is created properly, but the files for each counter are not generated at all. Can someone assist with where I am going wrong?

I attempted to modify the script for just one counter and one file, but I ended up with the same result. A directory is generated, but with no result file inside.

Viewing the hidden .txt file that is generated, I see that all of the results are there. What I want is all of the results for each counter to be placed into their own .txt file. For example, branch-instructions would have a file in the output directory called branch-instructions.txt and so on.

Comment: `$counter_name` is empty because of the trailing `/` in `$counter` .. you have to change `$NF` in `awk -F"/" '{print $NF}'` or removing trailing `/` from `$counter`

Comment: Perhaps `awk -F"/" '{print $(NF-1)}'`

Comment: Thank you for your response! From my understanding, the trailing / is already removed? I'm imagining this:
cpu/event=0x00,umask=0x01,name=batch-instructions/

will become this: 
batch-instructions

Comment: Already removed by what? You didn't take any steps to remove it before passing it to `awk`.

Comment: when you pass `msr/aperf/` to `awk`, and the input field delimiter is defined as `/`, `awk` sees 3 fields .... `msr`, `aperf` and `''` (blank == nothing after last `/`), so when you `print $NF` you're doing `print $3` which becomes `print ''`; this is going to happen for each entry in the array; I would expect a single output file named `.txt`

Comment: there's nothing in your code that comes anywhere close to parsing an input of `cpu/event=0x00,umask=0x01,name=batch-instructions/` to generate `batch-instructions`; the `awk` code parses by `/` (see previous comment) but other than that there's nothing that parses by `=` (or any other delimiter other than `/`)

Comment: for each `$counter` value please show the expected `$counter_name`

Comment: Thanks @tjm3772 the $(NF-1) got what I was originally expecting.

Comment: The counter names are expected to be branch-instructions, branch-misses, bus-cycles, cache-misses, instructions, msr/aperf, etc @markp-fuso

Comment: msr/aperf as a filename or just aperf??

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code like this (I only show the modified part, integrate the rest of your code in this):

```
#!/bin/bash

counters=(
    "cpu/event=0x00,umask=0x01,name=branch-instructions/"
    "cpu/event=0x00,umask=0x02,name=branch-misses/"
    "cpu/event=0x00,umask=0x0e,name=bus-cycles/"
    "cpu/event=0x00,umask=0x08,name=cache-misses/"
    "cpu/event=0x00,umask=0x00,name=instructions/"
    "msr/aperf/"
    "msr/mperf/"
    "msr/pperf/"
    "msr/smi/"
    "msr/tsc/"
    "power/energy-cores/"
    "power/energy-pkg/"
    "power/energy-ram/"
)

for counter in "${counters[@]}"
do
    counter_name=$(echo "$counter" | awk -F"[/=]" '{print $(NF-1)}')

    echo "$counter_name"
done
```

- The difference is in the awk like that sets the value of counter_name.
- `-F"[-=]"`: tells awk to use both `/` and `=` as deliminters.
- like you already found out, `$(NF-1)` gives you the second to last delimited value.

The output of my code above is:

```
$ ./so.bash 
branch-instructions
branch-misses
bus-cycles
cache-misses
instructions
aperf
mperf
pperf
smi
tsc
energy-cores
energy-pkg
energy-ram
```

Answer (score 0):

just skip the shell `for …`  loop entirely and do it in one-shot :

```
printf '%s\n' "${counters[@]}" |
```

---

```
{m,n}awk '$!NF = $--NF' FS='/|=' 

gawk -F'=|/' '$_=$--NF'
```

---

```
branch-instructions
branch-misses
bus-cycles
cache-misses
instructions
aperf
mperf
pperf
smi
tsc
energy-cores
energy-pkg
energy-ram
```